# Add ASP.NET Web API Authentication in Visual Studio 2015 to existing project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, when selecting a Web API template, we can now select No authentication, Individual User Accounts, Organizational Accounts, or Windows Authentication. Visual Studio then generates large quantities of code and includes many nugget packages automatically.

If I already have an ASP.NET Web API project without authentication, is it possible to add all of the generated code and packages for one of these authentication options without having to rebuild the solution from scratch or manually add each package?

Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

If you use the nuget package manager to search for identity you should be able to install it from there. There is an equivalent nuget command line incantation for nuget too:
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre

Be careful though. The current version is prerelease and it may also install a number of dependent components Which may cause issues.

As with all such things, taking a full backup of the solution before starting the process is advisable!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that would generate all of the code that you get when you use the Web API template with the authentication??

Comment: Maybe the only option is to use the new template and then retrofit the existing code into it?

Comment: @DeborahK If you add the Owin ASP.NET Identity package and the ASP.NET Identity Entity Framework package then you just need to add a bit of stuff in the Global.asax file and you're done.

Comment: @DeborahK At least for "individual user accounts;" if you want a different scheme you need different packages.  Also if you want to use ASP.NET Identity with EF you need to change your context to inherit from `IdentityContext<TUser>` instead of `DbContext`.

Comment: Sure wish it was well documented somewhere that for type x security you need these three NuGet packages and for type y security you need these four NuGet packages, and so on. One of the problems with NuGet is that it is often quite difficult to tell which packages you really need.

Comment: @DeborahK Well, the easiest way to figure it out is probably to just create a new project using the template and see what the account controller is doing.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how to mark this then to say that there is no good answer? (Not that the answers provided aren't good!) :-)

Comment: @DeborahK Well, there is one, if you or someone else looked at the template and figured out all the specific files you needed... it's just a bit of effort to figure it out.  Anyway I've done this before and it's not impossible.